# Data Type error when parsing through sqlite table

Tags: c#, sqlite

Say I have a table and I want to parse it's data. For example, table abc has a column called `Seq`. I want to parse through the column `Seq` to see if there are any irregularities. Example: if there's a number > 10 I want to let the user know.

I'm getting 2 errors, one regarding the data type and another regarding my list. What I plan to do with the list is to use it to display the irregularities to the user through a message box,

*I don't know much syntax at all So here's what I think:*

```
string sql4 = "select * from abc";
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql4, sqlite_conn);

SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
Convert.ToInt32(reader);
while (reader.Read())
{
    if (reader["Seq"] > 30) // Getting error: operator cannot be applied to
    // type objects and int
    {
        Parse1.Add(reader["Seq"]);
        // Another error saying that the best overloaded method for the string type int
        // Has some invalid arguments
    }
}

private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (object o in Parse1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(o.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is of type `object`:

```
reader["Seq"]
```

But you're trying to use it as an integer.  To do that, you should parse it into an integer first.  Maybe something like this:

```
int seq;
if (int.TryParse(reader["Seq"].ToString(), out seq))
    if (seq > 30)
        Parse1.Add(seq);
```

C# is a statically-typed language so the data types need to be consistent for the compiler.  The `"Seq"` value in `reader` may *intuitively* be a number, but computers don't have intuition.  You need to actually convert it into an integer to use it as one.

Comment: It should we worth noting that the original values in the db, column seq are not ints

Comment: @user7068: In that case you're going to run into problems when you try to compare them to an int: `if (seq > 30)`

Comment: That's why I tried to convert them into integer first : refering to the Convert.ToInt32(reader) part of the code. I'm not sure if I did that right

Comment: And as expected that statement (the convert.Toint one) is giving me an error: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader' to type 'System.IConvertible'.

Comment: @user7068: Definitely not.  For starters, I would fully expect that to fail on `reader` since `reader` is a complex object and not an integer value.  Second, even if it did succeed you don't actually assign the result to anything, so you never use the converted integer.  In any event, `int.TryParse()` is usually a better approach for converting an integer-ish value (from a string, for example) into an `int`.

Comment: @user7068: The approach doesn't logically make sense anyway.  In the `while` loop is where you access each individual numeric value from the data.  So you need to convert that value (`reader["Seq"]`) to an integer within the loop.  For values which aren't integers (as you indicate can happen), what do you plan to do?  Skip/ignore them?  `int.TryParse()` returns false if the conversion to an integer fails, so my code will silently ignore non-integer values.  If you want to respond to them in some way, just add an `else` block.

Comment: What I basically want to do is
1) Read the column values from Seq
2) If any value in Seq is >10 I just want to show that to the user 

What I dont understand is why you use int seq

Comment: How do you store anything in int seq for you to be able to test it in the if clause

Comment: @user7068: The call to `int.TryParse()` stores the result of the conversion in `seq` (notice that it's an `out` parameter... which I'm normally against for this very reason, in that it's not intuitive, but for `TryParse()` it's necessary because the return value is already a `bool` indicating whether or not the conversion was successful).

Comment: Your method works perfectly but I'd just like some clarification of this : if (int.TryParse(reader["Seq"].ToString(), out seq))
Can you please explain what exactly is going on.

So far I understand that it's trying to convert seq variable to int. But what does out seq mean and how do the values in the actual column ["Seq"] get transfered or relate to the variable int seq? What's the connection between them? Thanks!

Comment: @user7068: All that method does is try to convert the first argument into an integer and set that integer to the second argument.  If the conversion succeeds, the second argument will have the integer value and the return value will be true.  If it fails, the second argument will have its default value (0) and the return value will be false.